# UILabel with 0 lines doesn't initially show full text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

In my UITableViewCell, when I load data into it, I have 2 UILabels which can have an unlimited number of lines.

I handle both of them like this:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
```

When I initially load data into the UITableView, for some reason sometimes the cells on the screen don't yet show the whole String in the labels. Instead they just don't enlarge themselves.

However, when I scroll down so that they're off the screen and then scroll back up, everything looks perfect.

Why is this? How do I fix this issue?

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I basically use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(:forIndexPath:)`

then, I do `cell.configureViews(...)` and return.

In my PostCell I do the label editing above in the `override func layoutSubviews()`

Comment: how does your cellAtRowIndexPath method look like?

Comment: If you're using the storyboard, check to see if number of lines is also 0 there

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to set the 0 lines property on the storyboard too...

Go to your Storyboard, select the label, and click Attributes Inspector.

Under Label you should see "Lines 0" like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Also, make sure you are handling the excess of characters the way you want -  below is an example of the settings to wrap the text to a new line:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did this, but still I could not get my whole text to appear for the cell I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your UILabel height and use it as cell height before the cell drawn.

Try this to calculate the UILabel height [UILabel height calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908453/uilabel-height-calculation/33908477#33908477)