# UILabel height calculation

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UILabel` that the text is dynamically change based on server data. Sometime the data is so long that make my `UILabel` become multiline. Is there any way to calculate the height of my `UILabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var labelHeight : CGFloat
labelHeight = theLabel.boundingHeightForFixedWidth(theLabel.bounds.width)
```

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using Autolayout then no need to calculate height, just add leading,top and trailing constraint, set number of line to 0 for that label and line break mode to word-wrap, it will automatically update its height.

P.S. Add the bottom contraints too if there is any other control in nib after label.

Comment: Yeah, i know it, but unfortunately i can't use Autolayout for this project, thanks :)